# How to run a Java console application that uses Sockets in the cloud?

Tags: java, sockets, cloud, console-application

I can't seem to find a simple way to get my Java console app in the cloud. I thought it would be as simple as uploading it. I'm willing to pay money of course. My console app just takes data from the client, computes some stuff, and sends it back to the client. Is there any way to put my Java console app in the cloud? If not, what's the easiest alternative?

Comment: Have you tried it? There is no reason this should not work so long as you ensure there is access to the port the socket is listening on both on the server and in the cloud environment.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run a java application on a server you will need to setup a server for java applications to run on.

Personally I do this with `Tomcat` and then when I want to access my application I go to the url of my server and then add the port to the end of it,

```
http://www.example.com:8080
```

If you go [Here](http://tecadmin.net/steps-to-install-tomcat-server-on-centos-rhel/)

You can follow along with a nice tutorial walking you through this on a RHEL server.